# Dropdown data onMouseOver

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am writing a php page where when the mouse hovers over a link, more links and some info should drop down.  Thing is, I have no idea how to do this.

I've put in some javascript, and I can get the id of the div that I want to drop down. Setting the visibility, however, doesn't work as that just makes that block appear or disappear. Do I need to add and remove blocks? I would prefer if the solution does not need to reload the page, and css is, at best, a last resort.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showElement(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}
function hideElement(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

For those of you that suggested I use jquery, here is my attempt, based on what you gave me and some googling:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('a#').each( function(){
            var $id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('a#'+$id).hover(function(){
                $('div#'+$id).toggle();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

It doesn't work. Admittedly, that's not surprising, seeing as I never looked at jquery before yesterday.  Still, I have no idea what is wrong with it (probably quite a few things). What it is trying to do is iterate through all the links, then when hovered over, the div with the same name should display. Or that's the theory.

Comment: If you want the links to appear when you hover a link, CSS is virtually a MUST. Otherwise, how would you create an overlay and set its position relative to the mouse? Obviously the CSS would be minimum but'd make it much easier. The only way other than CSS would be reserving a div space to make your hidden div appear as you've demonstrated in your JS (or dynamically generate it) - or with `display:none` which would hide it without occupying space, but it could potentially mess up your page design if not done correctly.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté is right you need css in order to style it and position them on your page. What does your html look like and where would you like to position the dropdown? If you are not comfortable writing css try using something like Twitter bootstrap [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: Hi there is  spelling mistake  in javascript code. you put `getElemtneById` it must be `getElemenetById`. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the spelling error. It's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using a javascript library like [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to manipulate dom elements. Below is a very basic example of `hover` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/LC7Fy/1/

Check out [jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) for other usage examples.

Comment: The only problem with the hover event is that once you leave the link's hovering area, your `#content` div will vanish making it impossible to click in the links inside of it. It's a nice event for tooltips of sorts, but in OP's case it might not be very useful unless he wants to troll the users or add a couple workarounds to that. :P

Comment: If you make your hidden div inside of the div with the hover function it might work. Obviously, OP would have to create div/spans/containers/wrappers for each link then.

Comment: I don't want to steal all of your code so here is the updated working version (with wrapper) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/juVj4/1/)

Comment: I just threw this here to show him how jquery looks like. This is not the code he's meant to use for sure.

Comment: Oh I see :) I agree, JQuery is obviously much easier to type, understand and even learn. I don't know if forcing it on starters is a good practice, but seeing as even my friends which have close to no javascript experience are learning it quite quickly I can see your points.

Comment: Adding a div as in Fabricio's comment works. The only problem is that I'm not sure jquery is on the server I am using. I will be able to test this tomorrow.

Comment: jquery is a javascript library not a php extension. You just need to add the library (see the code above) to your html pages to use it. @FabrícioMatté i think jquery is the way if all you need is playing with dom elements. yet there are too much to learn for a dev anyways. I myself never actually a big fan of javascript, jquery changed my pov to it.

Comment: I think I can get this to work. My only problem right now is that I have to use php to figure out the id of the div that will be toggled. I don't know how not to hard-code the toggle IDs.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect my problem with jquery.  Mainly that I don't understand it.

Comment: Check my new example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LC7Fy/1/ you must do more reading and experimenting to get the basics but it's all very very simple.

Answer (score 1):

There is spelling mistake in your javascript code. You have used `getElemtneById` but it should be `getElementById`.

And for use `style.visibility = "visible";` for make visible div or span that must be `visiblity:hidden` css property. then only this will be work. If there is `display:none` then you can use javascript as given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showElement(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
 }
 function hideElement(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
 }
 </script>
```

I hope it will be helpful for you,
thanks

Comment: The problem with this is that after the block disappears, hovering over the link won't make it reappear...